# Difference between std::uncaught_exception and Microsoft __uncaught_exception?

Tags: c++, exception, std

It seems the C++ std library had [`std::uncaught_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception), and Microsoft has this [`exact function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1atwat8.aspx).

But Microsoft also has [`__uncaught_exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770584.aspx).  I don't see any notable difference in the documentation.   So, is there a difference?  If both are available to me, should I prefer one, the other, or use them both just to be sure?

```
// Option 1
if (uncaught_exception())
{
    // report it.
}

// Option 2
if (__uncaught_exception())
{
    // report it
}

// Option 3
if (uncaught_exception() || __uncaught_exception())
{
    // report it
}
```

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: @Deduplicator What is strange is that according to documentation, `std::uncaught_exception` has been there since VS2003, but `__uncaught_exception` appeared only in VS2010 - what for?

Comment: @AntonSavin: Exactly the problem.  You said it better. :)  And shame on Microsoft for not explaining it themselves.  Their documentation consistently leaves out the most significant aspects.

Comment: Maybe because `std::uncaught_exception` is a C++-function in namespace `std`, thus not useable from most other languages... Anyway, you cannot trust MS documentation on when something was introduced. Re-worked documentation regularly forgets there was anything before the then supported versions.

Comment: It is simply the implementation function, vendors can add underscored identifiers as they please or need.  Why they decided to document it isn't crystal, it does get used in the concurrency runtime however.  Use the std function of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether there is a difference or not, it does not matter much. The premise that lead to the creation of that function is inherently flawed and it is basically useless.

The function is meant to be a test to determine whether there is an exception in flight while this code (a destructor or code called from a destructor) is being executed, which would indicate that the stack is unwinding and that a second exception will terminate the program.

Except that it won't. Two exceptions cannot be active in the same stack frame, but there can be more than one exception in flight. An exception is thrown, the stack starts unwinding and one of the destructors for the local objects ends up calling code that throws an exception while *inside* a `try` block. Perfectly legal and fine, two exceptions in flight at the same time unwinding different parts of the stack.

The function `std::uncaught_exception` can thus not be used to determine whether throwing a new exception will cause `std::terminate` to be called and the main reason for the design is lost. Ending with a function serving no good purpose.

I cannot imagine any use case where `std::uncaught_exception` could be put to good use. And for the original intended purpose, just make sure that your destructors are `noexcept(true)` (which is the default in C++11 and above) and *don't throw*

Comment: I am using uncaught_exception in DEBUG code to track down an unknown, unexpected exception.  I am *not* using it to prevent throwing a second exception.  I am using it to determine if an object is being destroyed "normally", or due to an exception.

Comment: @abelenky: But you don't know... what if while stack is unwinding a destructor calls your function? There is already an uncaught exception, but you are not being called as part of stack unwinding. The function does not tell you that information, it gets deceptively close without actually telling you enough information. You don't know that the code is being run during stack unwinding, there is not sufficient information.

Comment: Its *debugging* code.  Partial information, clues & ideas is better than no information at all and being left completely in the dark.  When this function returns true, I know that there is an uncaught_exception *somewhere* nearby, even if not immediately in my current stack.  And that is enough info to debug on.

Comment: If `uncaught_exception()` is false at the start of a block, then at the end of the block, in a destructor for a local object, it tells you whether the block is exited due to an exception or not. Because how the block was called isn't changing. So Andrei's idea of a sort of automatic commit-or-rollback isn't infeasible, it's just that it can't be used, and relied on to do something, in code potentially called from within a `try` block called from within a destructor of stack based object. Which isn't all that common, after all.

Comment: I've verified that with Visual C++ 12.0 `std::uncaught_exception` and `__uncaught_exception` end up calling the same implementation function.